# Proper formatting of a JSON and multiplepart Guzzle post request

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5, guzzle

I have two different Guzzle post requests that I am trying to merge (solely because they basically do a united job and should be performed together).

Initially I have my donation data:

```
'donation' => [
       'web_id' => $donation->web_id,
       'amount' => $donation->amount,
       'type' => $donation->type,
       'date' => $donation->date->format('Y-m-d'),
       'collection_id' => NULL,
       'status_id' => $donation->status_id,
 ],
```

And then I have my files that go with it, which are basically two different PDFs that are enabled or disabled for donors, sometimes they have both. I know the multipart would look something like below, but I'm not sure.

```
                foreach ($uploadDocs as $doc) {
                        'multipart' => [
                            [
                                'name'     => 'donation_id',
                                'contents' => $donation->web_id,
                            ],
                            [
                                'name'     => 'type_id',
                                'contents' => $doc->type_id',
                            ],
                            [
                                'name'     => 'file',
                                'contents' => fopen($doc->path, 'r'),
                                'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'],
                            ],
                        ],
                }
```

Since I've usually only handled one file at a time and I'm not sure how to merge the first block of code with the second for an appropriate Guzzle post request.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```php
$donationData = [
    'web_id' => $donation->web_id,
    'amount' => $donation->amount,
    'type' => $donation->type,
    'date' => $donation->date->format('Y-m-d'),
    'collection_id' => NULL,
    'status_id' => $donation->status_id,
];

$multipart = [];

foreach ($uploadDocs as $doc) {
    $multipart[] = [
        [
            'name'     => 'donation_id',
            'contents' => $donation->web_id,
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'type_id',
            'contents' => $doc->type_id,
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen($doc->path, 'r'),
            'headers'  => ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Than perform your request:

```php
$r = $client->request('POST', 'http://example.com', [
    'body' => $donationData,
    'multipart' => $multipart,
]);
```

Comment: I gave yours a test, but a syntax error appeared focusing on the end box bracket for the multipart[] and the comma after it (and right before the end curly bracket), saying the comma was unexpected. I tried just removing it but then it had a problem with the curly bracket at the end. For clarification I also did fix the apostrophe after $doc->type_id.

Comment: "I gave yours a test, but a syntax error appeared focusing on the end box bracket" - I copied your code, though your might not work too :) Anyway, I made an edit